# Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL version for the right syntax to use near 'Limit 100' at line 1

Tags: mysql

This is fairly a simple code that I am writing using PopSQL but every time I run SELECT the error shows up.

```
CREATE TABLE student (
     student_id INT PRIMARY KEY,    
     name1 VARCHAR(20),
     major VARCHAR(20)
);

DESCRIBE student;

SELECT * FROM student;

INSERT INTO student VALUES(3, 'John', 'Software');
```

Comment: I see no limit in the question

Comment: Hmm, your question does not contain the faulty `limit 100` in the query... difficult to help you :)

Comment: My guess is that PopSQL is adding some stuff to the statements, like phpMyAdmin does with a lot of menu-driven stuff. With phpMyAdmin, it is easy to find the full generated SQL statement, but I have never used PopSQL so I don't know where to look.

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of the error here with the queries that you are running?

Comment: Are you trying to run all these queries at once? It may be adding `LIMIT 100` to the end, which won't work. Try running them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I did a web search "popsql limit error" and the first result answered your question, uncheck the auto limit box.

https://popsql.com/docs/getting-started/writing-a-query